# Is it safe to eat the white “dots” in peaches?

Tags: food-safety, peaches

[image]

As you can see there are white "dots" where the seed used to be.

- Is it OK to eat them?
- What are they, anyway? (I was worried they're some parasite or disease of the fruit)

Comment: Frankly, those look like maggot pupal coverings.  As in flies.   I don't think they are part of the peach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Meh, How Bad Could it Be?

Been eating peaches with these things for as long as I can remember. I seem perfectly fine and nothing ever happened to ... OMG ALIENS!! AHHH!!!

## Harmless Callus Tissue

Anyways, more seriously, they're absolutely harmless and are just extra tissue called `callus tissue`, as sourced from these:

- http://www.hmcfarms.com/what-are-the-white-spots-that-appear-inside-a-peach-pit
- http://www.ehow.com/info_8774670_white-stuff-peach-pit.html
- http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_white_stuff_on_the_inside_of_a_peach

## Ok, But What Exactly is that Callus Thing?

> Plant callus (plural calluses or calli) is a mass of unorganized parenchyma cells derived from plant tissue (explants) for use in biological research and biotechnology. In plant biology, **callus cells are those cells that cover a plant wound.** - *from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/)'s article on [Callus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callus_%28cell_biology%29) <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>*

Comment: Solved by a simple web search, how embarrassing. I'll go stand in the corner of the internet now.

Answer (score 10):

I'm having a look on here, already being a member on the Garden and Landscaping section. My horticultural knowledge tells me those white bits aren't anything to worry about, they're just callus tissue (bits of undifferentiated cells) which are not uncommon in the flesh around peach pits. I'll admit the picture isn't a sufficiently good close up to see entirely clearly, but unless you can see them writhing (!), it's just callus tissue and perfectly safe to eat.

Comment: Thanks. As per not being a close enough image, did you notice the full size image link I posted below the image ?

Comment: I didn't, sorry, but I've had a look - callus tissue, so no worries.